# Java Stream - Collecting Parent-objects into a Set after applying flatMap()

Tags: java, set, java-stream, collectors

Is it possible to go back to the *parent-object* after applying `flatmap()` operation, and accumulate *parent-objects* into a set?

I have an `UnifiedOfferEntity` with set of other entity objects as a field:

```
public static class UnifiedOfferEntity {
    private Set<ContractDetailsEntity> contractDetails;
    
    // getters, etc.
}
```

I would like to filter through fields of the *parent-object* (`UnifiedOfferEntity`) like this:

```
 offersFromDB.stream()
     .filter(offer -> CollectionUtils.containsAny(preferences.getOwnedSkills(), offer.getSkills()) 
                   && CollectionUtils.containsAny(preferences.getOwnedSeniority(), offer.getSeniority()))
```

And then I would like to examine the nested collection, filter through child-objects (`ContractDetailsEntity`):

```
.flatMap(offer -> offer.getContractDetails().stream()
     .filter(cd -> cd.getSalaryFrom() >= preferences.getSalaryMin())
```

And finally, I need to move back to the *parent-object* and collect its instances into a Set after these filters.

I was trying with this:

```
List<UnifiedOfferEntity> offersFromDB = // initializing somehow

Set<UnifiedOfferEntity> result = offersFromDB.stream()
    .filter(offer -> CollectionUtils.containsAny(preferences.getOwnedSkills(), offer.getSkills())
                  && CollectionUtils.containsAny(preferences.getOwnedSeniority(), offer.getSeniority()))
    .flatMap(offer -> offer.getContractDetails().stream()
        .filter(cd -> cd.getSalaryFrom() >= preferences.getSalaryMin() &&
                      cd.getSalaryTo() <= preferences.getSalaryMax() &&
                      tocPreferences.contains(cd.getTypeOfContract())))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

But it creates a `Set` of `ContractDetailsEntity`, not `UnifiedOfferEntity`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform filtering based on the contents of the *nested collection* (a set of `ContractDetailsEntity`) and then accumulate *enclosing objects* (`ContractDetails`) for which provided `Predicate` has been evaluated to `true` by using built-in *collector* [`filtering()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector)), which expects a *predicate* and a *downstream collector*.

If I understood correctly, you need only instances of `UnifiedOfferEntity` which have all the `ContractDetailsEntity` that match a particular Predicate. To filter such *offers*, you can generate a stream of *contractDetails* and apply `allMatch()` with all the conditions you've listed (in case if it's sufficient when only one instance of `ContractDetailsEntity` meets the conditions - apply `anyMatch()` instead).

That's how it might look like:

```
List<UnifiedOfferEntity> offersFromDB = // initializing offersFromDB

Set<UnifiedOfferEntity> result = offersFromDB.stream()
    .filter(offer -> CollectionUtils.containsAny(preferences.getOwnedSkills(), offer.getSkills())
                  && CollectionUtils.containsAny(preferences.getOwnedSeniority(), offer.getSeniority()))
    .collect(Collectors.filtering(
        offer -> offer.getContractDetails().stream().allMatch(cd -> // a Predicate for evalueating ContractDetails goes here
                cd.getSalaryFrom() >= preferences.getSalaryMin()
             && cd.getSalaryTo() <= preferences.getSalaryMax()
             && tocPreferences.contains(cd.getTypeOfContract())),
        Collectors.toSet()
    );
```